Why is it impossible to achieve perfect curve offset in Blender
I have experimented with many methods of curve offset myself and have also used many node groups created by experts, but I am unable to accurately offset text curves perfectly. The ideal curve offset is similar to that in Illustrator. Currently, the most mature method I have seen is this curve offset method, but it still cannot solve the problem of overlapping points. Can we clamp these corners according to the distance between points

https://obsidian-data-1326798899.cos.ap-guangzhou.myqcloud.com/202412311027663.blend This my test file

It took me weeks to figure out a good offset algorithm in c#, it became so wildly complicated that doing it in geonodes would be a project in itself.

Is the code level already quite complex, and it's almost impossible to perfectly implement it with geometry nodes

It's just a hard algorithmic problem and nodes get in the way when solving hard problems, in particular the lack of a while loop and strict functional paradigm.

@DanielMöller tell me if I'm missing something, the way I would approach this is to calculate the offset for each point of the curve (there's a simple formula for this to counter cross-section deformation depending on angles), then for each segment (can convert to mesh temporarily and do for each edge) check neighboring points offsets dot the axis defined by the segment/edge. Then you can calculate what factor t of the entire segment the offsets will move and calculate a factor to make that sum up to 1 - that's the limit. Find the maximum limit of the spline. If lesser than required offset

...scale then don't worry about it and move all points. Otherwise reduce the offsets to that limit, merge point by distance (merge the two points that just forced clamping and just connected), and repeat.

Perhaps you could separate the spline around concavities, as in those places the points will never merge, and this would reduce the number of steps.

Related post ? Reduce text width to 0 (internal wire)

@MarkusvonBroady, after offseting segments, some loops will appear, you have to find the intersection point where the loop can be cut away. I used "is this segment inverted" as a criteria to find these loops, but a loop can contain one or more segments (arbitrary).  But there are more special cases, loops appear on the inside of curved segments, but inverted segments may appear in other places needing different treatment. Maybe there are many tricks with geonodes that can be used to avoid the calculations.

There is also a decision factor for some treatments. I checked Autocad offsets and GIS sofware offsets and they have different decision for some special cases (the most troublesome cases being tiny bends at the start or end of the curve, and absolutely weird results if the original curve has loops). Some softwares simply make a huge polygon  union (extending segments when gaps appear due to angle) and take the contour of this polygon (which may contain strange non intuitive spikes appearing, and not following the sequence of segments), but according to the polygon approach, it makes sense.

@DanielMöller with the algorithm I described you shouldn't get loops because you're clamping before you get a loop. I didn't play around with the idea so maybe I'm missing something.

Figured out a cool way using mesh boolean (heavy and slow, but good).
The example below shows many offsets with different distances, including one that colapses the curve (the nodes produce one offset only, the image here has many duplicated lines for showing different distances together)

Drawback: if the offset of one part of the curve touches the offset of another part of the curve, a mess might happen. In the example above you can see a tiny bit of line remaining from an offset that went too far.
Main nodes
The general setup does this:

Creates a profile to convert the curve to a mesh (this profile is a grid, one point of the grid at 0,0, one side at x = offset distance and the top at an arbitrary Y just to have a volume)

The grid has the offset vertices marked with an attribute


Converts the curve to mesh making a volume from the grid

The volume has the cap faces marked with an attribute


Performs a mesh boolen making a union with itself (removes overlaping and loops, faces inside the volume itself)
Selects only the faces that are vertical and contain some of the interpolated offset attribute
Deletes the cap faces
Selects only the edges that are on Z = 0


Create profile group

Creates a plane (grid with only 4 vertices)

Size X = offset distance
Size Y = arbitrary


Offsets the plane (make one side at X = 0 and one side at Y = 0)
Sets an attribute to the vertices that are not on X = 0 (they will make the offset line)
Converts to curve


Create volume

Converts the curve to mesh using the plane/grid to make a volume
Sets the vertical faces that have the offset attribute in between (neither 0 nor 1) as "cap" faces using an attribute


Vertical face

Just checks if a face is vertical based on its normal


File:

